# what are the factor i should test in Live Video Streaming in iOS?

Tags: ios, ipad, unit-testing, video-streaming

I am testing one iPad Application which Includes Live Video Streaming.I am not aware of what should i test and How Should I test this iPad Application?Now I am using KIF as automated testing tool.Please provide some suggestion regarding this.I am new in iPad application testing.